# Show integer coordinates on axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

If I plot the following graph I obtain a point 1020 on the x-axis instead of 1024 as intended. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=log, 
xlabel=Threads per block, 
ylabel=Time (s),
legend pos=north west,
xtick={data},
xticklabel={%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
    \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
}
]

\addplot table {
1   8.87E+00
2   1.09E+01
4   8.79E+00
8   5.53E+00
16  4.53E+00
32  5.17E+00
64  5.10E+00
128 5.28E+00
256 1.00E+01
512 2.09E+01
1024    4.26E+01

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Execution times when using one thread per row of the solution matrix's grid.} \label{fig:opr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @dexteritas done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- increase precision to `precision=4`
- use `round( ... )` to get an integer
- set `width` and `height` to avoid overlaps

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.9\textwidth,
height=70mm,
xmode=log, 
xlabel=Threads per block, 
ylabel=Time (s),
legend pos=north west,
xtick={data},
xticklabel={%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
    \pgfmathparse{round(exp(\tick))}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=4]{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
}
]

\addplot table {
1   8.87E+00
2   1.09E+01
4   8.79E+00
8   5.53E+00
16  4.53E+00
32  5.17E+00
64  5.10E+00
128 5.28E+00
256 1.00E+01
512 2.09E+01
1024    4.26E+01

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Execution times when using one thread per row of the solution matrix's grid.} \label{fig:opr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Variant with 2^x as ticks

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

Replace two lines inside `xticklabel={ ... }` with:

```
    \pgfmathparse{round(ln(exp(\tick))/ln(2))}%
    $2^{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=4]{\pgfmathresult}}$
```

Comment: is there a way the x labels don't appear as overcrowded as they are?

Comment: You could increase the overall size with: `width=0.8\textwidth` or write the xticks as `2^x`.

Comment: you mean as xtick={2^x}?

Comment: I added a variant with 2^x to the answer and changed the size of the first variant.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect, that you like to have the following result:

[image]

In comparison to your MWE has the following differences:

- increased are distances between ticks that labels are more easy to read
- enlarged are x limits
- defined are tick labels styles
- used is different (simpler) way to calculate x tick labels

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=log,
xlabel = Threads per block,
ylabel = Time (s),
% changed styles
     x = 9mm,
enlarge x limits = 0.05,
 ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize,
                    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
     log basis x = 2,
      xticklabel = \pgfmathparse{2^\tick}
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
            ]
\addplot table {
1       8.87E+00
2       1.09E+01
4       8.79E+00
8       5.53E+00
16      4.53E+00
32      5.17E+00
64      5.10E+00
128     5.28E+00
256     1.00E+01
512     2.09E+01
1024    4.26E+01
};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```